# Python: Counting names in list of dictiopnaries

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, count, stanford-nlp

I have extracted a list of dictionaries from Stanford NER and created a list like the following :

```
myList = [
{'A':{},'B':['C','D'],
'names': {'PERSON': [u'John Butters', u'Bill', u'Hillary Clinton'],'LOCATION': [],
 'ORGANIZATION': [u'FactSet', u'Pfizer Inc. PFE']}},
{'A':{'Hello'},'B':['F','E'], 
'names': {'PERSON': [u'Tim Anderson', u'Hillary Clinton'], 'LOCATION': [ u'US'], 
'ORGANIZATION': [u'Goldman Sachs GS', u'ConocoPhillips COP', u'FactSet']}},
{'A':{'right'},'B':['M','N'],
'names': {'PERSON': [u'Mohammed bin Salman', u'Spano'], 'LOCATION': [u'Saudi Arabia',u'Red Sea'],
 'ORGANIZATION': [u'Aramco', u'FactSet', u'Goldman Sachs GS']}}
 ]
```

In the other word I have a list like:

```
myList = [{},{},{}]
```

Each dictionary contains details for one specific document.  The key of 'names' is a dictionary like:

```
'names':{'PERSON':[], 'LOCATION':[], 'ORGANIZATION':[]}
```

I intend to extract the frequency of values under the key of 'names' ----> 'ORGANIZATION'  over the whole document, and then count how many times each pair of names occurred together in myList. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The output should look like:

```
{u'FactSet': 3, u'Pfizer Inc. PFE':1, u'Goldman Sachs GS':2, u'ConocoPhillips COP':1, u'Aramco':1}
```

And finally, I want to count co-occurrences of the above names. The output can be like:

```
{[u'FactSet', u'Pfizer Inc. PFE']:1, 
[u'Goldman Sachs GS', u'ConocoPhillips COP']:1,
[u'Goldman Sachs GS', u'FactSet'] :2,
[u'Aramco', u'FactSet']:1, 
[u'Aramco', u'Goldman Sachs GS']:1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses itertools.combination to easily get all pairs from a list:

```
from itertools import combinations

myList = [
{'A':{},'B':['C','D'],
'names': {'PERSON': [u'John Butters', u'Bill', u'Hillary Clinton'],'LOCATION': [],
 'ORGANIZATION': [u'FactSet', u'Pfizer Inc. PFE']}},
{'A':{'Hello'},'B':['F','E'],
'names': {'PERSON': [u'Tim Anderson', u'Hillary Clinton'], 'LOCATION': [ u'US'],
'ORGANIZATION': [u'Goldman Sachs GS', u'ConocoPhillips COP', u'FactSet']}},
{'A':{'right'},'B':['M','N'],
'names': {'PERSON': [u'Mohammed bin Salman', u'Spano'], 'LOCATION': [u'Saudi Arabia',u'Red Sea'],
 'ORGANIZATION': [u'Aramco', u'FactSet', u'Goldman Sachs GS']}}
 ]

orgs_by_group = [group['names']['ORGANIZATION'] for group in myList]

org_counts = {}
org_pair_counts = {}

for org_group in orgs_by_group:
    #Update counts of orgs
    for org in org_group:
        if org not in org_counts:
            org_counts[org] = 1
        else:
            org_counts[org] += 1

    #Update counts of org pairs
    for pair in combinations(org_group,2):
        k = '|'.join(sorted(pair)) #<-- key for org_pair_counts dict
        if k not in org_pair_counts:
            org_pair_counts[k] = 1
        else:
            org_pair_counts[k] += 1

print('Org counts:')
print org_counts
print('')
print('Org pair counts:')
print org_pair_counts
```

OUTPUT:

```
Org counts:
{u'Pfizer Inc. PFE': 1, u'ConocoPhillips COP': 1, u'Goldman Sachs GS': 2, u'FactSet': 3, u'Aramco': 1}

Org pair counts:
{u'Aramco|Goldman Sachs GS': 1, u'Aramco|FactSet': 1, u'FactSet|Goldman Sachs GS': 2, u'ConocoPhillips COP|FactSet': 1, u'ConocoPhillips COP|Goldman Sachs GS': 1, u'FactSet|Pfizer Inc. PFE': 1}
```

NOTE: You can't have lists be keys in a dictionary, so your example output for the coincidences doesn't work, that's why I've made them strings